# Convert array cells based on quote character that wraps cells

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this `a=['"nam', 'e"', '"numb', 'er"']`. I want to create another array based on this array's cells. if the cell starts with a quote, then track the next cell that ends with a quote and declare that a cell for the new array. here's an example of how the array will become after conversion:

```
converted_array=['name', 'number']
```

Keep in mind that the array might be in this format

```
a=["'name", "e'", "something", "'numb", "er'"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Will this`'"numb', 'ber"'` not result in `numbber`?

Comment: What is `a` doing in front of the brackets? That is not valid JavaScript notation. Not also that individual slots of an array are generally termed "elements" if they contain values.

Comment: I edited the post @HereticMonkey sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Check this code

```js
const myArr = ['"My', 'Number"', 'hello', '"text--', '12345"'];

let result = [];
let status = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  let r = myArr[i];
  if (r[0] == "'" || r[0] == '"') {
    result.push(r.slice(1));
    status = 1;
  } else if (r[r.length - 1] == "'" || r[r.length - 1] == '"') {
    result[(result.length - 1)] += "" + (r.slice(0, -1));
    status = 0;
  } else if (status == 1) {
    result[result.length - 1] += (r);
    status = 1;
  } else {
    result.push(r);
    status = 0;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's a nice idea mate thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out

```js
const myArr = ["'My", "Nu'mber", "hello'", "text--'", "12345'hou", "se'"];

const result = []
const delimiter = "'"
let closing = false
let tempText = ''
for (const item of myArr) {
  if (!closing) {
      if (item.startsWith(delimiter)) {
        tempText += item
        closing = true
      } else {
        result.push(item)
      }
  } else {
      tempText += item
      if (item.endsWith(delimiter)) {
        result.push(tempText)
        tempText = ''
        closing = false
      }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you solution has a problem. For this input `["'My", "Number", "hello", "text--'", "12345'hou", "se'"]` It gave me this result `[ 'MyNumber', 'hellotext--', '12345hou', 'se' ]` which is wrong.

Comment: It's a smart solution but it still has problems. I tested it with this input `["'My", "Number", "hello'", "text--'", "12345'hou", "se'"]` and it gave me this `[ 'MyNumberhellotext--', '12345house' ]`. the result should be like this `["MyNumberhello", "text--'", "12345'hou", "se'"]`.

Comment: I hadn't read the instructions well. I think I solved now

Comment: Nice job! It works now. thanks for the time you put into this. Really appreciate it.